how to avoid 408 error in JSF application
I have JSF application run on tomcat with basic authentication. When it is left unauthorized for some time like 20 minutes or more it gives the following error, when I try to log in. How can I avoid it?

HTTP Status 408 – Request Timeout
Type Status Report
Message The time allowed for the login process has been exceeded. If you wish to continue you must either click back twice and re-click the link you requested or close and re-open your browser
Description The server did not receive a complete request message within the time that it was prepared to wait.
Apache Tomcat/8.5.14

